# PHP table elements not filling in properly

Tags: php, html-table

I have this table in PHP:

```
 echo "<table style='border-style:none;'>";
 echo "<tr>";
if (!$goon) {
    echo "<td colspan=2 style='border-style:none; text-align:center;'>You have ".$_GET['Tries']." tries to guess my word.</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td colspan=2 style='border-style:none; text-align:center;'>";
    echo "<select id='bet' size='1' style='width:150px;'>";
    echo "<option value='0'>Bet";
    for ($i=0; $i<=5000; $i+=100) {
       echo "<option value='".$i."'";
       if ($i == $_GET['Bet'] && $_GET['Bet'] != 0) {
          echo " selected='selected'";
       }
       echo ">".$i."</option>";
   }
   echo "</select>";
   echo "</td>";
   echo "</tr><tr>";
   echo "<td id='letters' colspan=2 style='border-style:none; color:white; text-align:center; font-size:14px;'>Letters guessed - ".$_GET['Letters']."</td>";
   echo "</tr><tr>";
   echo "<td colspan=2 style='border-style:none; text-align:center;'>";
   echo "<table style='border-style:none;'>";
   echo "<tr>";
   $l = count($ans);
   for ($i=0; $i<$l; $i++) {
      echo "<td style='border-style:none;'><input style='width:30px;' id='w".$i."' type='text' value='".$ans[$i]."' /></td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "</table></td>";
   echo "</tr><tr>";
  ?>
  <td colspan=2 style='border-style:none; text-align:center;'><input type='button' value='Guess' onClick='hangman("<?php echo $_GET['Word']; ?>",<?php echo $_GET['Tries']; ?>);' /></td>
  <?php
  echo "</tr><tr>";
  }
  echo "<td colspan=2 style='border-style:none; color:white; text-align:center; font-size:14px;'>".$msg."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>";
```

While the array `$ans` has values c,o,m,e,t. When the table displays, shouldn't the TD's be filled in with c o m e t? For some reason they're blank.

Comment: I edited your code. Now give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing ' in your line. Change

```
echo "<td style='border-style:none;'><input style='width:30px;' id='w".$i."' type='text value='".$ans[$i]."' /></td>";
```

with

```
echo "<td style='border-style:none;'><input style='width:30px;' id='w".$i."' type='text' value='".$ans[$i]."' /></td>";
```

and it should be fine

It is a common error, you can use a different approach that is simpler to proofread. I prefer something like this:

```
for ($i=0, $limit=count($ans); $i<$limit; $i++) {
  printf ('<td style="border-style:none;"><input style="width:30px;" id="w%s" type="text" value="%s"/></td>', $i, $ans[$i]);
}
```

Comment: That didn't fix it. I don't see the difference between your line and mine.

Comment: in your code you have `type='text value=` that is utterly wrong. you have to change that code with `type='text' value=` that has an extra `'`

Comment: that didn't fix it either, I also trie the printf solution but that didn't work either

Comment: The problem is fixed. I'm not sure what fixed it though :(

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td style='border-style:none;'><input style='width:30px;' id='w".$i."' type='text' value='".$ans[$i]."' /></td>";
```

replace with

```
 echo "<td style='border-style:none;'><input style='width:30px;' id=w".$i."type=text value=".$ans[$i]." /></td>";
```

Comment: You should be more clear with your answer. What do you mean by just writing some code here?